# How to search for postings of user X with tag Y?

Tags: support, search

Suppose I want to search for postings of a known member John Doe under the tag Calculus. What steps do I take?

Similarly:
How do I search for responses of user X to questions which have tag Y?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The search-query is

`[tag-name] user:UserNumber`

for all posts of the user with number UserNumber in the tag tag-name.

If you want to restrict to question or answers add `is:q` or `is:a` respectively.

Answer (score 5):

You can also go to the users profile and find the tags tab: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=tags Then click on the tag which you are interested in.

When you do this, you will see what the syntax is. For example, when searching for your post in [calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus) tag you would use: `user:29038 [calculus]` https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:29038+[calculus]

Answer (score 4):

You could use [this search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A13854+[combinatorics]) to look for all my posts tagged [combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics). Modify the user and the tag as needed.